# References of research papers which lead to starting of Sieve Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

> Question -  I am thinking to present one or two papers on Sieve Theory in my masters thesis. I will also present 3 other papers on Riemann Zeta Function which I have studied earlier . But I have no previous knowledge of Sieve Theory. Although I know about some books in sieve theory like Montgomery ( Topics in multiplicative number theory) , Friedlander and Iwaniac ( Sieve theory: A musical) but my Institute only accepts research papers in masters thesis.

So, can any researcher here suggest 2 research papers which led to the beginning of the subject of sieve theory. I will study them and present them along with the papers I have already studied.

I have searched in past 4-5 days for some papers in different domains of ANT over web pages of different professors and some other websites  but it doesn't lead me much as I am just a beginner in this field.

Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted because your lifestory has no relevance and is not suitable on MO.

Comment: You also mentioned other things like "being abandoned by a professor" and that you did not manage to read a paper and that you want to talk about something but do not know what it is.

Comment: "I started working on masters thesis as per guidance of a professor not of my Institute who abandoned me and didn't even bothered to tell." Yes, you've told us this several times now. May I suggest that you find another professor, at your institute, who will give you an idea for a master's thesis & help you with it? Trying to write a thesis without supervision is asking for trouble, and MathOverflow is not a substitute for a supervisor.

Comment: I have nothing to contribute, concerning sieve theory. Have you considered working in something other than Number Theory? Have you considered transferring to another institute? These may not seem like attractive options to you, but they may be better than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Flooding MO with edits of your old questions that already have accepted answers seems to me to be an abuse of this website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's just been edited again (2022-01-05 in this timezone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sieve theory as such is generally considered to have started with Brun's 1915 and 1919 papers. The titles are "Über das Goldbachsche Gesetz und die Anzahl der Primzahlpaare" and ""La série $1/5+1/7+1/11+1/13+1/17+1/19+1/29+1/31+1/41+1/43+1/59+1/61+\cdots$, où les dénominateurs sont nombres premiers jumeaux est convergente ou finie".

Legendre's sieve predates Brun's sieve, but it seems to be thought of more of a precursor to sieve theory than anything else.

Comment: can you please tell where I can find original paper these?

Comment: Or English translations but of both of these papers!! I searched the internet. I can find A book "Goldbach conjecture " But it will not have papers (original ) Although 1st paper is given in its references. But i have no clue about 2 nd? Can  you please tell where they are available!!

Comment: The 2nd paper is at https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k486270d/f138.item.r=brun

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks for the help.